# How to pass specific column search criteria in DataTable jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am pretty new to jquery DataTable.
I want to search on a specific column name say 'name' with values neo, meveric etc.

myTable is object of DataTable.

```
myTable.search({'name':['neo', 'meveric']}).draw();
```

Can any one help me to perform search with above data.

Plz Help.

Thanks

M.

Comment: are you trying to search with all or any of those 2 terms? or perhaps you want the term to search only inside name column? it's rather unclear, please add more details

Comment: Yes, i want to search above two values in name column only..

Comment: Searching from user input or you want to search by code?

Comment: by checkbox.. I want to know to pass data to search function..

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward:

```
nameColumnIndex = 1; // replace this by the actual index for your specified column
searchTerm = 'John'; 
myTable
  .column(nameColumnIndex)
  .search(searchTerm)
  .draw();
```

[Documentation.](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html)